# jquery mobile assign var onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, onclick

I have a list and I want to set a variable when an item in that list is clicked.

```
<li><a href="#secondpage" onclick=""><img src="images\HF1.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb">text</a></li>
```

I want to use onclick to set variable X to a certain value. For example onclick X will be set to purple. Anyone know how I can do this?

Regards,

Comment: In your <img> tag, give it an ID. In your <a> tag, you have an attribute "onclick". Create an `onclick function` that accesses the ID of your img.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  var z;
  $(".x-var-setter").click(function(e){
    z = $(this).attr("data-color");
  });
});
</script>

<ul>
  <li><a data-color="purple" href="#secondpage" class="x-var-setter" onclick=""><img src="images\HF1.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/A8bPy/

HTML:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
    <li id="purple"><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li id="red"><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li id="orange"><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$('ul[data-role="listview"] li').bind('click',function(event, ui){
    colors.activeColor  =  $(this).attr('id');
});

var colors = {
    activeColor : 'none'
}
```

I have used a variable inside an object, its a variation on your request. Take a look at my example to see how is it working. Listview can have as many elements this event will work on everyone of them + it will return li unique value.